# Buck-Boost IC LM5118

Tags: switch-mode-power-supply, buck-boost

I read the TI Buck-Boost IC [LM5118](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/lm5118.pdf?ts=1628840831317&ref_url=https%253A%252F%252Fwww.ti.com%252Fproduct%252FLM5118), this is a Wide Voltage Range Buck-Boost Controller, but I am confused about something.

1. Do you know how to calculate the current stress on D1, D2, Q1, Q2?because the datasheet doesn't explain it. so I don't know how to choose the right component.
2. On page 27, how to get the equations 11 and 15. can someone give some advice?

[image]

Comment: You could use TI's Webench tool to get the stresses on the components if you don't know how to calclulate them.

Comment: @JohnD Can you tell me where I can see the stresses on components because I just see the recommended component, not the stress.

Comment: "Stress" is just the power dissipation of a component (and how hot it get because of it), so all you need to do to find out how stressed a component gets is simulate the circuit and find the power dissipated in the components.

Comment: @EEC You can print the design report from Webench, and it will include the stress levels on all the main components.

Comment: @JohnD the design report doesn't tell me the MAX current. can you give me an example? because I still don't find it

Comment: @JohnD I think the Webench is wrong, because I run this simulation in buck converter mode, in theory the M2 should turn off and no current through it, but the simulation report show it has a current. Do you think this is correct?

Comment: @EEC I doubt Webench is wrong, it's probably giving you the peak current in the entire operating range you specified.  Maybe try specifying a single Vin for the operating condition you want to examine rather than a range.  I don't have time at the moment to go dig into this.  If you're strictly in buck mode, you should be able to use the equations for a buck converter to calculate the component stresses.  Find the ripple current in the inductor, and the peak current is the load current plus inductor ripple/2.

Comment: @JohnD OK, I understand, thanks for your answer.